# jQuery not working in a looped form

Tags: php, jquery

I have a looped form and each one has a submit button and i added javascript that when i clicked, it will not redirect to other page

But when i try to submit javascript isn't working it redirected to other page I hope someone can help me

These are my code from my loadProduct function

```
<?php
include('../classes/class.product.php');

$cat = $_POST['categ'];
$p= new Product();
?> 

<table class="w3-table table table-bordered w3-striped w3-card-4">
<thead>
<tr class="w3-green">
  <th>Product Name</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Remaining Stock </th>
  <th>Add to List</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<?php
$list_of_product=$p->loadAllProductAccToCategory($cat);

    foreach ($list_of_product as $product) { 
    ?>

       <tr>

         <td><?php echo $product->prodname; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $product->price; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $product->remaining_stock; ?>Piece(s)</td>

         <td>
           <form class ="<?php echo $product->prodname; ?>" action="functions/InsertOrders.php" method = "POST">
              <input class='form-control' name='qty' type='text' placeholder="Enter Quantity" autocomplete="off" required />  
              <input type="hidden" name='en'  value=<?php echo $product->id; ?> />
              <input type="hidden" name='price'  value=<?php echo $product->price; ?> />
              <input type="hidden" name='rstock'  value=<?php echo $product->remaining_stock; ?> />

              <button <?php if ($product->remaining_stock<1) { ?>
           disabled="true" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'
           <?php } ?> class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil <?php echo $product->id; ?>'>Add</button>
           </td>
        </form>
     </tr>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(".<?php echo $product->id; ?>").click(function(){

    $.post( $(".<?php echo $product->prodname; ?>").attr("action"),$(".<?php echo $product->prodname; ?> :input").serializeArray(),function(sv){alert(sv);})
    clear();
  });


  $(".<?php echo $product->prodname; ?>").submit(function(){
    return false;

  });

  function clear(){
    $(".<?php echo $product->prodname; ?> :input").each(function(){
      $(this).val('');
    });
  }
</script>
       <?php
  }
?>


</table>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript">

  $(".sub").click(function(){

    $.post( $(".myForm").attr("action"),$(".myForm :input").serializeArray(),function(sv){alert(sv);})

  });


  $(".myForm").submit(function(){
    return false;

  });

  function clear(){
    $(".myForm :input").each(function(){
      $(this).val('');
    });
  }
</script> -->
```

Comment: You have opened <td> and <form>, you're closing </td> and </form>. Take a look in your 4th <td>.

Comment: there is .. below sir.. before closing form

Comment: You have inverted the tags, try <td><form (...)>(...)</form></td>

Comment: And you have to trigger jQuery's events in a $(document).ready(). Event binding needs to work with DOM in it's 100% rendering state.

Comment: You're redefining `clear()` every time through the loop. There can only be one function with that name.

Comment: @RPichioli That's not necessary, because the event bindings are after the HTML that creates the element.

Comment: Don't create a separate event binding for each form. Give all the forms the same class, and use an event binding to the class. Then use `$(this)` in the callback function to refer to the form being submitted.

Comment: You don't have the `.sub` button in the html.   Make sure it isn't `type='submit'` which is the default if not specified, so specify:  `<button type='button' class='sub ...`

Comment: @Barmar I agreed, the problem could be the clear() call as you said

Comment: @RPichioli You're also correct about the `</td></form>` being wrong, it should be `</form></td>`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you redefine `clear()` because it's (re)defined as exactly the same each time (no closures etc).

Comment: So this table+form is created multiple times?  Each form will have class ".myform" - the submit function `$.post( $(".myForm").attr("action")...` will submit **all** forms with that class.

Comment: its in't type submit sir

Comment: the jquery is just working in the last loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".<?php echo $product->id; ?>").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post( $(".<?php echo $product->prodname; ?>").attr("action"),$(".<?php echo $product->prodname; ?> :input").serializeArray(),function(sv){alert(sv);})
    clear();
});
```

This may work

Comment: not redirecting to other page but only last loop will only works in saving data